# Why Rational Team Concert changes the files' last modified attribute?

Tags: version-control, ibm-rational, rational-team-concert, ibm-jazz

I'm having some issues with the installation of Rational Team Concert on my server.

The thing is that when I upload some changes to the server (any kind), it changes the last modified attribute of the file, but it shouldn't do it.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This is something that we have tried to add to RTC SCM (and we still plan to).  However, we found that it needs to be an option on load/update.

There are numerous details and discussions available @ [this work item on jazz.net](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=83718)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding timestamp, getting over the fact that relying on it in a version control tool isn't always considered a best-practice (see "[What's the equivalent of use-commit-times for git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964470/whats-the-equivalent-of-use-commit-times-for-git)"), it is actually a complex issue:

- an SCM loader wouldn't use just timestamp to determined what file has changed ([Task 179263](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&itemId=_yijSsO3IEeC6QPXP3XX4bA))
- you can have various requirements for that timestamp (like in [Defect 159043](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&itemId=_e0e9UFYBEeCOBbLKjM8odQ), where the file timestamp of the modified file on disk that of when it was delivered, not when I accepted.). The variable `JAZZ_CCM_SKIP_MOD_TIME=true` is mentioned so check if that could improve your specific case.
- it is all based on the assumption the timestamp is correctly set by the local workstation, which isn't always true, as illustrated in [Task 77201](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&itemId=_INPQkR_OEd6gT_fz7RhQTg)