# One-Time Git Commit using Filesystem Created as Author Date

Tags: git, timestamp, commit, timeline, git-commit

I have a project of which I have about 6 backup folders, each named after the date of the backup.   I am moving these to a Git system, and I want to preserve the date/time the files inside were created.  I do not want to use one date for all files in each backup (as I have seen in other SO questions), and I do not intend to use filesystem dating moving forward, as that would break tools like `make` etc.   I would like to "bring git up to speed" as it were, by committing each of these backup folders using the filesystem creation date *of each file* as the author date, and the last modified as the commit date.  This is a one time process that I will repeat 6 times, after which I will commit normally.  Is there a way to do this?  I'm really trying to preserve the code timeline.  Thanks!

Comment: so use the filesystem date and pass it into `git commit`'s `--date` option?

Comment: There are thousands of files and all examples I've seen show `--date` changing to a single, specified date.  I want to set the dates per file...

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to set the right date for each and every file (which would mean one commit per file), you could record those dates in a file, and have a post-checkout hook able to restore those dates.

See "[What's the equivalent of use-commit-times for git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18682037/6309)" for an example of such a script, which will store [mtimes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_%28system_call%29) in a `.mtimes` file in git repository, and restore those mtimes on checkout.