# Using Git Clone to convert svn repository to git repository on Windows

Tags: git, svn, tortoisesvn, tortoisegit

I have installed on Window 10 TortoiseSVN, an recently Git and TortoiseGit.
Up to now I have only used TortoiseSVN.

I would like to convert my SVN repository into Git.

In the Internet I found the following link, which describes how the conversion can be done.

https://smexyyweby.wordpress.com/2013/09/13/clone-svn-repository-to-git-using-tortoisegit-on-windows/

I tried it and everything went well, except the modfied date of all files is set to the actual date.

**How can the files in the cloned Git repository can keep the modified date as it is in the SVN repository?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the equivalent of use-commit-times for git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964470/whats-the-equivalent-of-use-commit-times-for-git)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+preserve+file+timestamp

Comment: Short answer: no, git doesn't preserve timestamps on files, only on commits.